# How using DataContext from singleton in repository?

Tags: c#, singleton, data-access-layer

Ef generate `MyDataModel.edmx` with `class MyDataEntities` for my database MyData.
I create a singleton class `SingletonMyDataContext`

```
public sealed class SingletonMyDataContext
    {
        private static readonly MyDataEntities_instance = new MyDataEntities();
        private SingletonMyDataContext() { }
        static SingletonMyDataContext() { }

        public static MyDataEntitiesInstance { get; private set; }
    }
```

I want to create a Repository class for work with data in DB, but i don't now, how to use in repository context(MyDataEntities _instance), because after using need call `dispose()`.
How using DataContext from singleton in repository?

```
public class Repository
{
private DbContext _context = SingletonMyDataContext.Instance;

//logic for work with data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How using DataContext from singleton in repository

Obviously, you should not make your data context as a singleton. Moreover, in most cases it's a bad practice. EF data context caches metadata itself, after first creation of context instance. Don't try to do it twice.

Comment: Thats mean, don't create a singleton, simple use repisotory?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean.